# Finding density plot for histogram

Tags: probability, statistics, graphing-functions

Let's say we have a pdf $f$ of a continuous random variable $X$. If we draw $n$ iid variables and create a histogram with $m$ equally sized bins, what is the equation of the function that we should superimpose on the histogram as a density plot?

For example, if $X\sim\mathcal U[0,1]$ and we have $5$ bins and $10000$ trials then we expect a frequency of $2000$ in each bin so we should superimpose the function $2000f(x)$ where
\begin{align}
f(x)=\begin{cases}
1 & 0\leq x\leq 1\\\\
0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
\end{align}
How can we find what the scaling factor is in general?

Comment: Hint 1: $5$ bins in $[0,1]$ leads to a bin size of $0.2\,.$ Hint 2: $f(x)\cdot 0.2$ is the *percentage* of trials you expect in the bin that $x$ falls into. Hint 3: the histogram presumably plots the *absolute* number of trials.

Comment: Having said that: for a uniform distribution the histogram should look quite boring. You will learn a lot more when you try another $f(x)\,.$